# Can't fetch data from Branch io Url

Tags: ios, branch, integration

https://find-work.test-app.link/78jlmUvzaT

This is the url I have generated using branch io test mode and passing some data along with the URL.

If I try the below link I am getting all the data related to that URL
https://find-work.test-app.link/78jlmUvzaT?debug=true

But while clicking the link, it redirects me to the app but I can't fetch the parameters which is stored in the url.....Always getting Clicked_branch_link = 0..Help me out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this issue as well, for ios (swift) you need to call 
`Branch.setUseTestBranchKey(true)` before initializing branch io assuming it's in dev or test.